# response.write not working in embedded function on nodejs

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I seem to have a problem which seems to elude me entirely. My current node config is:

```
var url = require('url');
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var server = require('http').createServer(function(request,response) {
  switch (url.parse(request.url).pathname) {
    case '/mongotest':
      mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function(err,db) {
        if(!err) console.log('Connection successful!');
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
        response.write('Text to output to browser');
      });
      break;
    case default:
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
      response.write('Request for ' + url.parse(request.url).pathname + ' received.');
  }
  res.end();
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Everytime I go to /mongotest, the console logs 'Connection successful!', but there doesn't seem to be any output on the browser at all, and neither does the writeHead seem to at all.

Any help?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `res.end()` is supposed to be `response.end()`, you're calling `response.end()` before your `res.write` calls in the async `connect` callback.

You need to move that call into the callback, like this:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function(request,response) {
  switch (url.parse(request.url).pathname) {
    case '/mongotest':
      mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function(err,db) {
        if(!err) console.log('Connection successful!');
          response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
          response.write('Text to output to browser');
          response.end();
      });
      break;
    case default:
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
      response.write('Request for ' + url.parse(request.url).pathname + ' received.');
      response.end();
  }
});
```